# Website title is wrong when sharing link on facebook, or liking website

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, share, page-title

Ever since adding the code for facebook like buttons and the meta tags, my website now has a problem when being shared on facebook. If you put the link "http://podawful.com" into facebook it comes up with the title being "Derp" instead of "Pod Awful".

I have no idea why.  "derp" is nowhere in my code.  This sounds so stupid, but its true.  Any help?

website for reference:

http://podawful.com

Comment: Things look fine in the debugger. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpodawful.com%2F

Comment: @ceejayoz - it's likely that if it was broken for the OP you fixed it by running it through the debug tool, which clears Facebook's previously loaded cache of the site metadata

Answer (score 20):

In general, check the debug tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug which will show what information Facebook has detected on your page as well as updating Facebook's cache of that information

I don't see the 'Derp' title when I try to share on Facebook, for example:[image: screenshot from when I share your URL]

Comment: I added a screenshot of what I see when I share that URL - are you sure it's not after fixing the cache since you ran the URL through the debugger?

Comment: Everything is good now.  Except the posts that get liked on the first page show the wrong image.  Every other post on any other page displays correctly, but not those first 3.  Thanks you for your help.

Comment: If the debug tool shows the correct image, it should be fine on Facebook.com also, as the information from that tool populates Facebook's cache of your page when it's Liked or Shared - are the article pages themselves showing the correct image in the debug tool?

Comment: It shows it correctly in the debug, which means running the debug is probably correcting it for them as well.  thanks for all the help.

Comment: Yes, running debug will pick up any changes you've made. Otherwise, it takes 24-48 hours to be reflected.